# apt-btrfs-snapshot: Exception when trying to delete snapshots

Tags: apt, filesystem, btrfs

On Ubuntu, when you run `apt upgrade` it creates a btrfs snapshot, if you use this file system. The problem with this, is that after a while you endup with problems writing to disk because having too many snapshots exhaust the maximum number of Inodes the file system can have.

So there is the `apt-btrfs-snapshot` tool to manage and most importantly delete oldsnapshots. however mine has been raising the following exception when I try to list snapshots (`apt-btrfs-snapshot list`):

```
Available snapshots:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-btrfs-snapshot", line 103, in <module>
    res = apt_btrfs.print_btrfs_root_snapshots()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_btrfs_snapshot.py", line 212, in print_btrfs_root_snapshots
    print("  \n".join(self.get_btrfs_root_snapshots_list()))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_btrfs_snapshot.py", line 204, in get_btrfs_root_snapshots_list
    atime = os.path.getatime(os.path.join(mp, e, "etc", "fstab"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 60, in getatime
    return os.stat(filename).st_atime
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/apt-btrfs-snapshot-mp-4uisiasm/@apt-snapshot-release-upgrade-bionic-2018-02-26_14:51:59/etc/fstab'
```

Does anyone know how to getaround this error so that I can properly manage my snapshots and avoid catastrophe yet again (running out of Inodes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an easy answer! 
Despite getting the error reported above, I tried to directly delete the offending snapshot:

```
sudo apt-btrfs-snapshot delete @apt-snapshot-release-upgrade-bionic-2018-02-26_14:51:59
```

and it worked!! after that, I ran the following command to delete the remaining ones:

```
sudo apt-btrfs-snapshot delete-older-than 1d
```

And it proceeded to delete all the remaining snapshots!